# Get class reference from routes flutter

Tags: flutter

Presume I have three classes: `main`, `EndpointList` and `FillDataClass`.

I have defined some routes in my main class as such:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Named Routes Demo',
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => MyApp(),
      '/endpoint_list': (context) => EndpointList(),
    },
  ));
}
```

My EndpointList class is a simple list view:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EndpointData {
  EndpointData(this.name, this.id, this.token, this.isIncoming);

  final String name;
  final String id;
  final String token;
  bool isIncoming;
}

class EndpointList extends StatefulWidget {
  EndpointList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EndpointList createState() => new _EndpointList();
}

class _EndpointList extends State<EndpointList> {
  List<EndpointData> endpointList = <EndpointData>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // build and show list
  }

  void insertEndpoint(EndpointData endpointData){
    endpointList.add(endpointData);
  }

}
```

My question is, how can I access and instance of EndpointList, from class that is not main, in order to call the insertEndpoint method?

In my java mind, I want to do this:

```
Endpoint endpoint = new Endpoint(); // This is done in route in main class
```

And then from class `FillDataClass` (presuming `endpoint` has been properly instanced in `FillDataClass` via constructor):

```
endpoint.insertEndpoint(data);
```

How can I create and access endpoint in order to populate, and then display, my list?

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate the Endpoint class which will contain an insertEndPoint mothed.

```
class EndpointData {
  EndpointData(this.name, this.id, this.token, this.isIncoming);

  final String name;
  final String id;
  final String token;
  bool isIncoming;

  List<EndpointData> _endpointList = <EndpointData>[];

  void insertEndpoint(EndpointData endpointData){
    _endpointList.add(endpointData);
  }

}
```

Then in your UI

```
class EndpointListUI extends StatefulWidget {
  EndpointListUI({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EndpointListUI createState() => new _EndpointListUI();
}

class _EndpointListUI extends State<EndpointListUI> {

  //You can create instance from anywhere and insert data to it
  List<EndpointData> endpointList = <EndpointData>[];
  endpointList.add(endpointData);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // build and show list
  }


}
```

Comment: If data is generated when pressing a button, your solution would mean for each button pressed, a new `EndpointData` would be created so rather than one instance with 5 datas, I'd have five instances with a single data. Correct?